# Divert to alternate homepage if user is not logged in using UI-Router & AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, authorization, angular-ui-router

I would like to have two home pages, the first would be for users who have not logged in and the second for users that are logged in.

This is my current set up:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  })

  .factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
      // Add authorization token to headers
      request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
        }
        return config;
      },

      // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
      responseError: function(response) {
        if(response.status === 401) {
          $location.path('/login');
          // remove any stale tokens
          $cookieStore.remove('token');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      }
    };
  })

  .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      if (next.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        $location.path('/login');
      }
    });
  });
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            title: 'Home',
            mainClass: 'home',
            headerSearch: true
          });
      });
```

How could I reconfigure this so I could do something like the following:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('welcome', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/welcome/welcome.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeCtrl',
        title: 'Welcome',
        mainClass: 'welcome',
        isLoggedIn: false
      });
     $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        title: 'Home',
        mainClass: 'home',
        isLoggedIn: true
      });
  });
```

Comment: I think you should refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005250/angularjs-dynamic-stateprovider)

Comment: There is also module [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for this

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to show, how we can manage authentication driven access to *states*. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725180/1679310) and its [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLABnz?p=preview), we can enrich each state *(which should be accessible only for authenticated users)* with a **`data`** setting, explained here: [Attach Custom Data to State Objects](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects) *(cite:)*

> You can attach custom data to the state object (we recommend using a data property to avoid conflicts)...

So let's have some states with public access:

```
// SEE no explicit data defined
.state('public',{
    url : '/public',
    template : '<div>public</div>',
})
// the log-on screen
.state('login',{
    url : '/login',
    templateUrl : 'tpl.login.html',
    controller : 'UserCtrl',
})
...
```

And some with private access:

```
// DATA is used - saying I need authentication
.state('some',{
    url : '/some',
    template : '<div>some</div>',
    data : {requiresLogin : true }, // HERE
})
.state('other',{
    url : '/other',
    template : '<div>other</div>',
    data : {requiresLogin : true }, // HERE
})
```

And this could be hooked on on the state change:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'User', function($rootScope, $state, User)
{

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
    , function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    var isAuthenticationRequired =  toState.data 
          && toState.data.requiresLogin 
          && !User.isLoggedIn
      ;

    if(isAuthenticationRequired)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('login');
    }
  });
}])
```

See all that in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLABnz?p=preview)

There is similar Q & A were I try to show the concept of redirecting Authenticated and Not Authenticated user:

- [Angular UI Router: nested states for home to differentiate logged in and logged out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191768/)

*maybe that could help to get some idea, how we can use `ui-router`, and its event '$stateChangeStart' to hook on our decision manager - and its forced redirecting...*

Answer (score 2):

the code should be something like this

```
     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState)                { //, fromParams
       console.log(toState.name + "," + fromState.name);
        if(fromState.name === "") {
          if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
              $state.go('welcome');
               event.preventDefault();
          } else {
            $state.go('home');
               event.preventDefault();
        } else {
           if (toState.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
               $toState.go('login');
               event.preventDefault();
           }
        }
    }
```

so if user entering the application, then if he is logged in take him to `welcome` else take him to `home`.

once he is inside, then if he hits some route which needs auth.. then redirect him to login page..

sorry if i did not understood you requirement fully...

Comment: I gave this a try but all I got was an error saying `stateChangeStart` doesn't exist. I removed it so just using  `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart');` and that didn't throw an error but instead it just didn't work.

Comment: Am I meant to put this inside `.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {`?

Comment: I found the missing colon but now I get `ReferenceError: $state is not defined`

Comment: Ok, the now gives `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: have you inject your auth service?? can you setup plunker, ??

Comment: This will show how I have set up the JS if you look in scripts.js http://plnkr.co/edit/9IrNSPLEtExn6pddrTsg

Comment: can you please provide complete plunker.. not just js.. you have two modules with same name btw.. can you please read basics of ui router

Comment: I don't know how to set up the auth in Plunkr as I am using Angular-Fullstack. And the module names don't seem to be interfering with anything else.

Comment: but the most basic part is, you can have two modules with same name... atleast as far as how i understand it...

Comment: hummm, I will look into that, but for now things are working (you'll have to bear with me I am trying to learn angular atm so I might be a bit slow and thats the reason why I'm trying to understand). I have readdressed the plunkr, so perhaps it's a bit more readable, but it still doesn't work as the whole auth part is a bit beyond me when it comes to setting up a plunkr. But atleast you can see where I am making the mentioned changes and perhaps where I am going wrong.

Comment: I now get this error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: you are much closer to solution.. check the edit.. added    `event.preventDefault();` to all the routes

Comment: It works with `event.preventDefault();` on all urls except `The maximum call stack size exceeded` error remains. but If I change `if(fromState.name === "")` to `if(fromState.name = "")` the error goes but then it doesn't update the states.

Comment: try to debug why is it comingn so many times in this loop and you would mostly get the solution

Comment: I have tried to debug but all I can see is that this `(anonymous function) angular.js:7299
Scope.$broadcast angular.js:12889
transitionTo angular-ui-router.js:2032
go` is being called over and over again. I even read this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/618 which covers a similar issue but no luck. This method simply causes my app to either crash or create an infinite loop on the state. I am simply wanting to redirect to a different state if a user logs in, surely it's not to difficult.

Comment: The other problem I just relalised is if I go from the initial state to another, lets say '/login' and then go back to '/' (still not logged in) I will see the 'home' state which is meant to be hidden to visitors and only visible to people who are logged in. I'm guessing this is due to using `fromState` is there another way around this?

Comment: `console.log(toState.name + "," + fromState.name);` added console.log.. can u check the output in console

Comment: All I get is `400 console messages are not shown.
897
welcome,
3
welcome,` But as I say this only works when I first load the app when that state is '' but if I go to about and then come back it now  sees state from not as '' but 'about' and loads 'home' but it should only ever load home if a user is logged in regardless of what pages they visit prior to logging in.

Comment: please analyze tostate and fromstate and debug little bit should solve the problem...

Comment: What you have done is exactly what I have done. But it still doesn't change the fact that my question originally was how do I make it so that if a user comes to my app and is not logged in they see 'welcome' and if they come and they are logged in they see 'home' this means that no matter what page they visit if they come back to the base url '/' they will see 'welcome' only logged in users will ever see 'home'.

Comment: Where should `rootscope` code go? Inside a `.config(..)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
.config(function ($stateProvider,$rootScope) {
$stateProvider
  .state('welcome', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/welcome/welcome.html',
    controller: 'WelcomeCtrl',
    onEnter: function() {
      if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
         $stateProvider.go('home');
      }
  });
```

});

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. It still just defaults to 'home'

Comment: I found that a brace was missing so I get the following error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cbuiRouterApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootScope`

Answer (score 0):

I had problem like this and I solved it like this

```
 .run(function ($rootScope, $location, AuthService) {

        // start showing PRELOADER because we doing async call and we dont know when it will be resolved/rej
        AuthService.checkLoginStatus().then(
            (resp) => {
                // fire logged in user event
                $rootScope.$broadcast('userLogged',resp);
                $location.path(YourHomePageUrl);

            },
            (err)=> {  
                // Check that the user is not authorized redirect to login page                  
                    $location.path(loginURL);
                }
            }).finally(
            ()=> {
                // finnaly Set a watch on the $routeChangeStart
                /// Hide PRELOADER
                $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
                    function (evt, next, curr) {
                      if (!AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
                                $location.path(art7.API.loginURL);
                            }

                    });
            }
        )


    });
```

and im not using interceptor for handling 401 not authorized errors, thats my solution

Comment: Its in typescript , AuthService was my service for authentication