# Confusing $locationChangeSuccess and $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to do some authentication with AngularUI Router. `$urlRouter.sync()` looks like exactly what I need. However, that's only available when I intercept `$locationChangeSuccess`. But when I do that, `$state.current.name` is empty, whereas I want it to be the current state.

Here's my code so far:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, next, nextParams) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($state.current.name === 'login') {
    return userService.isAuthenticated().then(function(response) {
      var authenticated;
      authenticated = response.authenticated;
      return alert(authenticated);
    });
  }
});
```

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Err... What about `$stateChangeSuccess`?

Comment: Then I can't use `urlRouter.sync()`

Comment: `$state.current.name` will only be empty on the initial page load. Any state changes triggered after that will have a state name. If all you need to do is enforce authentication, then listen on `$stateChangeStart` - you don't need to worry about `$urlRouter.sync()`. There are plenty of examples around that demonstrate that.

Comment: Can you share what is the requirement??

Comment: @IanB - "There are plenty of examples around that demonstrate that." where?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would suggest to go more "`UI-Router` way". We should use `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'` event where `$state.current` would be properly provided. Here is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/H3gqq1hy0OeS6a1WRnWJ?p=preview)

Let's observe simple *(but not naive)* solution, which could be extended to any degree later. Also if you will like this approach, here is much more comprehensive implementation: [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22537311/1679310)

Firstly, let's have our user service defined like this:

```
.factory('userService', function ($timeout, $q) {

    var user = undefined;

    return {
        // async way how to load user from Server API
        getAuthObject: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // later we can use this quick way -
            // - once user is already loaded
            if (user) {
                return $q.when(user);
            }

            // server fake call, in action would be $http
            $timeout(function () {
                // server returned UN authenticated user
                user = {isAuthenticated: false };
                // here resolved after 500ms
                deferred.resolve(user)
            }, 500)

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        // sync, quick way how to check IS authenticated...
        isAuthenticated: function () {
            return user !== undefined
                && user.isAuthenticated;
        }
    };    
})
```

So, we use async *(here `$timeout`)* to load **`user`** object form a server. In our example it will have a property `{isAuthenticated: false }`, which will be used to check if is authenticated.

There is also sync method `isAuthenticated()` which, until user is loaded and allowed - always returns `false`.

And that would be our listener of the `'$stateChangeStart'` event:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'userService',
 function ($rootScope, $state, userService) {

     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState,   toParams
                                                        , fromState, fromParams) {    
        // if already authenticated...
        var isAuthenticated = userService.isAuthenticated();
        // any public action is allowed
        var isPublicAction = angular.isObject(toState.data)
                           && toState.data.isPublic === true;    

        if (isPublicAction || isAuthenticated) {
          return;
        }

        // stop state change
        event.preventDefault();

        // async load user 
        userService
           .getAuthObject()
           .then(function (user) {

              var isAuthenticated = user.isAuthenticated === true;

              if (isAuthenticated) {
                // let's continue, use is allowed
                $state.go(toState, toParams)
                return;
              }    
              // log on / sign in...
              $state.go("login");
           })
       ...
```

What we are checking first, is if user is already loaded and authenticated *(`var isAuthenticated = ...`)*. Next we will give green to any public method. This is done with the `data {}` property of the state object definition (see [Attach Custom Data to State Objects](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects))

And that's it. In case of states defined like in a below snippet we can experience:

- the `'public'`, `'home'` are allowed to anybody
- the `'private'`, `'private'` will redirect to login if `isAuthenticated === false`
- the `'login'` in this example provides quick way how to switch isAuthenticated on/off

  ```
  // States
  $stateProvider

    // public
    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        data: { isPublic: true },
    })
    .state('public', {
        url: "/public",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        data: { isPublic: true },
    })
    // private
    .state('private', {
        url: "/private",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    })
    .state('private2', {
        url: "/private2",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    })

    // login
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        data: { isPublic: true },
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
    })
  ```

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H3gqq1hy0OeS6a1WRnWJ?p=preview)

Some other resources:

- [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22537311/1679310)
- [Angular UI Router: nested states for home to differentiate logged in and logged out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25191768/1679310)
- other [state `data` and authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25029935/1679310)

Comment: I'm wondering.. maybe doing an http request per time the route changes is to much traffic, wouldn't be better set an auth user object part of windows or a service to see if the user is aunthenticated ?

Comment: If I understand your issue properly, good news is **solved** ;) Angular `provider` model *(including `services` and `factories`)* is driven by **singleton** pattern. So the **`userService`** in our example would be instantiated only **once**, only once will call the server *(here the `$timeout`)* and any next call to it will return `user` local variable... does it help?

Comment: ops.. yes, sorry I got confuse with getAuthObj and isAuth.. thanks