# ui-router - stop changing state on resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

On a specific state user is clicking link to other state in which there is a resolve condition that checks if user has permission. 
How to stop changing state to new one if user hasn't permission?

Comment: There are few similiar questions, check for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310). It should give you some idea, also, there is a working plunker.

Comment: OK. So not in resolve but on $stateChangeStart - thx

Comment: Exactly... this event could/should be the place for these "AOP" solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var routesThatRequireAuth = ['/user', '/account', '/messages']; 
var hasPermisions = false;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  if($.inArray(toState.url,routesThatRequireAuth)>-1 && !hasPermisions) {

    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
    // alert message
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, @Maciej. Thank you for taking the time to answer. In the future, i would recommend adding an explanation of how this answers the OP's (original poster) answer.