# Check user loginned on UI-Router

Tags: authentication, angular-ui-router

I have 1 variable to save data user when they logged in.

Var : `isLoginned`

When user logged in, i set `isLoginned = '1'` and save to **LocalStorage**.

I want to use `isLoginned` to check when router changes.

Check access to this router when user logged in Only. If not logged in, redirect to page sign in.

This is example code in Ui router

```
 .state('access.page', {
    url: '/page',
    templateUrl: 'app/Components/Page/Page.html',
    onEnter: function ($storage.isLoginned) {
       if ($storage.isLoginned != '1') {
            $location.path('/access/signin');
       }
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
       $scope.page.setTitle('Page title');
    }
 })
```

User Service

```
/**
 * Created by tatda_000 on 11/26/2014.
 */
'use strict';
app.factory('signinService', function ($http) {
    return {
        signin: function (user, scope) {
            //console.log('Test function');
            var $promise = $http.post('api/AccountController/Login', user); //post data to server
            $promise.then(function (msg) {
                //scope.msgtxt = msg.data;
                if (msg.data.Message != 'Success') scope.msgtxt = 'Tên tài khoản hoặc mật khẩu không đúng!';
                else scope.msgtxt = 'Success';
                //save user infomation to Local Storage

                scope.$storage.username = msg.data.Data.Username;
                scope.$storage.password = msg.data.Data.Password;
                scope.$storage.userToken = msg.data.Data.UserToken;
                scope.$storage.isLoginned = '1';

            });
        }
    }
});
```

User controller

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
// signin controller
app.controller('SigninController', ['$scope', '$localStorage', 'signinService', function ($scope, $localStorage, signinService) {
    //set page title
    $scope.page.setTitle('Đăng nhập');

    $scope.login = function (user) {

        signinService.signin(user, $scope); //call function login service


    };

    //create first value storage
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        username: "",
        userToken: ''
    });

    $scope.logout = function () {
        delete $scope.$storage.username;
        delete $scope.$storage.userToken;
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Regardles of the source (LocalStorage, $http and service singleton) there are few examples how to do that in UI-Router. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310) for example

Comment: thank you, but i don't understand, i have to added file [code]User service[/code] and [code]User controller[/code]. Pls help me. I'm New bie 
@RadimKöhler

Comment: The best you can do, create a plunker. Place it into your question, and I am sure you'll get an answer. I strongly suggest: create a plunker with your example...