# How to combine passport and angular-ui routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I'm wondering how I can combine angular-ui-routing with passport.
All examples I find are using the node.js routing there for.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })

    .state('about', {
        // for example just show if is loggedIn       
    });
```

How would I implement this function in the above snippet?

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Thanks for every hint

Comment: Does somebody know if it even works without much overhead?

Comment: If you do not mind, try to check this [Q & Q](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310) to see how to solve similar issue.

Comment: https://vickev.com/#!/article/authentication-in-single-page-applications-node-js-passportjs-angularjs This helps even more. It's from a google angular dev.

Answer (score 9):

One way to start is by creating a service in Angular that uses $http to hit your endpoint in Express. $http returns a promise with success and error methods you can use to change state. If you're building a Single Page App (SPA) this is probably all you need to know. For example:

```
// An Angular service that talks to Express
UserService.$inject = ['$http', '$state']; 

function UserService($http, $state) {

    this.loginUser = function (user) {
      $http.post("/api/login", user)
        .success(function (data, status) {
          console.log('Successful login.');
          console.log('data = ' + data); 
          console.log('status = ' + status); 
          $state.go('welcome'); // 
      })
        .error(function (data) {
          console.log('Error: ' + data);
          $state.go('somewhereelse'); 
      });
  };
```

$state.go is a UI Router convenience method that will render your defined state.

In Express you'll want to write your own callback function for Passport to control what is returned. For example:

```
 // Express Route with passport authentication and custom callback
  app.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
        return next(err); 
      }
      if (user === false) {
        res.status(401).send(info.message);  
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(info.message); 
      }
    })(req, res, next); 
  });
```

In this example, I'm using a 'local-login' Passport strategy that's working it's magic in the background. If the user is authenticated it will send a 200 back to Angular, which will in turn trigger .success. Otherwise it will send a 401 Unauthorized and fire off .error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found a complete solution which helps me a little bit more to realize my problem. https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport