# Roles Based Authentication for a sails.js web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authorization, angular-ui-router, sails.js

I am building a frontend using angular for a sails.js api backend. What is the best way to manage roles and rules-based routing in the angular app? I have been looking at UI Router as well, but I can't determine if UI Router has specific features to support this.

Comment: Please, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310 there is a clear example how to plus some other links ... ;)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow...