# UIRouter login redirection using $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular1.4,ui.router0.2.15. Trying to redirect to login state in $stateChangeStart. Here's the logic:

```
$rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart', function(){
  if(!isLoggedIn && toState.name !== 'login') {
    console.log('go to login');
    e.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login');
  } else if (isLoggedIn && toState.name === 'login') {
    console.log('go to home');
    e.preventDefault();
    $state.go('home');
  } else {
    console.log('no change');
  }
});
```

I thought the execution will be like:

```
event1: from:'', to:'home', 'go to login' 
event2: from:'', to:'login', 'no change' 
...then proceed
```

But in fact it is:

```
event1: from:'', to:'home', 'go to login' 
event2: from:'', to:'login', 'no change'
event3: from:'', to:'home', 'go to login'
event4: from:'', to:'login', 'no change',
event5: from:'', to:'home', 'go to login',
...the dead loop continues until max digest loop
```

I spotted that event3 is trigger in angular-ui-router.js `function registerState`:

```
// Register the state in the global state list and with $urlRouter if necessary.
    if (!state[abstractKey] && state.url) {
      $urlRouterProvider.when(state.url, ['$match', '$stateParams', function ($match, $stateParams) {
        if ($state.$current.navigable != state || !equalForKeys($match, $stateParams)) {
          $state.transitionTo(state, $match, { inherit: true, location: false });
        }
      }]);
    }
```

But I lost track of the problem since it's too complicated.

Why event3 fired??? And if I wanted my redirection should I register my own event like $myStateChangeStart???

Comment: I'd say that all that is covered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310

Comment: @RadimKöhler Are you saying register $stateChangeStart in app.run is not recommended? I checked $state.current in app.run is {
    "name": "",
    "url": "^",
    "views": null,
    "abstract": true
}

Comment: @RadimKöhler The problem is not I redirect to login twice but an invisible $state.transitionTo fired in ui.router itself...

Comment: In the link I gave you is a plunker, which is working. I would suggest to compare that with your stuff. UI-Router behaviour is expectable.. no invisible transitions, I'd say

Comment: @RadimKöhler I've heard urlRouterProvider does not work well with ui.router. And the problem here is exactly an invisible state transition fired by urlRouterProvider, if you look at the last piece of code in the question(also https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/release/angular-ui-router.js#L2346 ). And ui.router actually fires another invisible transitionTo in its handleRedirect function(https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/release/angular-ui-router.js#L2927).

Comment: @RadimKöhler And the first transitionTo ever is fired by that urlRouterProvider line, from '' to 'home'. It seems a '' to 'home' transition is fired again by urlRouterProvider(Apparently not me).

Comment: Sorry, I do not have another answer for you. That's why I added just a comment

Comment: @RadimKöhler that's why I love stackoverflow and all the enthusiastic people like you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92728/discussion-between-jchnxu-and-radim-kohler).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is the mechanism of ui.router. But I hacked it like doing the initial route change(aka. state '' to state 'home') not in the handler. But somewhere else. It seems to me the problem occurs only when the app first bootstraps.

Steps:

1.Make a root abstract state, doing the same redirection logic of the $stateChangeStart handler.

2.Add

```
if(!from.name) {
    return;
}
```

to the beginning of the $stateChangeStart handler.