# Accessing Current State using Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have states mentioned as

```
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: '',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {label: 'Home'},
            data: {freeRoute: true}
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: '',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {label: 'Dashboard'},
            data: {authenticatedRoute: true},
        })
```

I wish to run configuration in case if page is refreshed, like this

```
    .run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, AUTH_EVENTS, dataService) {
    if ($state.$current.data.authenticatedRoute == true) {
        console.log('Authenticated Route.');
        if (dataService.isAuthenticated()) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.alreadyAuthenticated);
        } else {
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Not Authenticated Route.');
    }
    });
```

But when I tried to log console on current state it gives me like this...

```
{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true}
```

-- How would I get current state. in controller? I have also tried `console.log($state.$current);`
-- How would I access in views as well, irrespective of controller?

Comment: The way I'd use is not just a .run() but listener on the `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'`... check it e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310

Comment: It has been done using $stateChangeStart. THanks

Comment: Really? ;) great to see that. Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir

Comment: I have question related to this. Can I modify this or ask another question? I have issue of 'too much recursion'. Because I change state in broadcast method.

Comment: You should issue a question, because here you have just me, with new question your audience and chance to get right answer will be increased...

Comment: ;) My playground is SO only. And I do answer only if I know *(I cannot guarantee that for each scenario, right ;)*. So, I'd really suggest: ask a new question here, and someone smart will hopefully give you the answer.

Comment: I requested u on SKP. Would be pleasure to add you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `console.log($state.current)` to be able to see currently active state's name, parent, url etc.

BTW, if you want to *quickly* see this detail in debug console using command line, you could use following kind of command in dev tool's debug console:

```
$("html").injector().get("$state").current
```