# using event.preventDefault() in ui-router causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

error:

[image]

Yes i know there have been posts similar to this one but they do not address my issue. I want to take full control of the app's routing.My code is as follows:

*a few things to note would be that i have attached a custom property to my states called authenticate which has a `true` or `false` value. I have also created a simple function, `get user`. All it does is retrieve the user from the api.*

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let token = $cookies.get('token');

  if (toState.authenticate) {
    if (token) {
      getUser()
        .then(user => {
          $rootScope.user = user;
          $state.go(toState.name);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    } else {
        $state.go('login');
    }
  } else {
      $state.go(toState.name);
  }
});
```

I first check if the state requires authentication. If it does not we simply continue to the state. If it does require authentication we check if there is a token. if there is we fetch the user using the function I mentioned earlier. If there isn't a token we send the user to the login state.

Comment: why do you need event.preventDefault(); there?

Comment: Because otherwise the app tries to go to the state without me being able to check if authentication is needed.

Comment: on what condition the event.preventDefault(); is called, its going infinite and its what the error is being thrown...

Comment: What do you mean, there is not a condition. I call it once the event handler fires.

Comment: You are calling event.preventDefault() every time there is a change in state... $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

Comment: There is a detailed explanation and working plunker http://stackoverflow.com/q/25872219/1679310

Comment: though I am aware @RadimKöhler's solution works well and so are the explanations well put, I highly recommend to use the `resolve` function in `ui-router`. It's cleaner and more elegant, and no global variables, yeay.

Comment: @CozyAzure this is a nice point. In case, that application (or state hierarchy) can be blocked - resolve is a standard - synchronous solution. In case, we want dispatch user with some features regardless security (anonymous) ... resolve will break it, because it is really blocking.. until resolved. But nice point