# AngularJS, ocLazyLoad & loading dynamic States

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

**app**

> ```
> define(['angular', 'angular-ui-router', 'ocLazyLoad', 'config/common', 
>         'layout/services/menuService'],
>
> function(angular) {
>     'use strict';
>     var $stateProviderRef = null;
>     var $urlRouterProviderRef = null;
>     return  angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'app.common', 'app.layout']);
> });
> ```

**app.config**

> ```
> define(['app'],function(app){
> app.config(function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
>     $urlRouterProviderRef = $urlRouterProvider;
>     $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
>
>     $urlRouterProviderRef.otherwise('/');
>     $locationProvider.html5Mode({enable: true, requireBase: false}); //.hashPrefix('!');
>     $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
>         events: true,
>         debug: false
>     });   }); });
> ```

**app.run**

> ```
> define(['app'],function(app) {
> app.run(function ($q, $rootScope, $state, $window, menuSvc) {
>     menuSvc.all().success(function(viewStates) {
>         var startUp = undefined;
>         angular.forEach(viewStates, function(viewState, key){
>             var viewStateUrl = undefined;
>             if (viewState.isStartUp == true && startUp == undefined) {
>                 startUp = viewState.name;
>             }
>
>             var state = {
>                 "url": viewState.url,
>                 "name": viewState.name,
>                 "views": []
>             }
>
>             angular.forEach(viewState.views, (function(view) {
>                 var myView = {
>                     "controller" : view.controller,
>                     "templateUrl" : view.templateUrl,
>                     "resolve" : { }
>                 };
>
>                 myView.resolve.loadController = function($ocLazyLoad)
>                 {
>                     return $ocLazyLoad.load(
>                         {
>                             "name": view.moduleName,
>                             "files": view.controllerFiles
>                         })
>                 };
>
>                 state.views[view.viewName] = myView ;
>             }));
>
>             $stateProviderRef.state(viewState.name, state);
>         })
>         $state.go(startUp);
>     })
> }); });
> ```

**Solved:**

The error was in a combination of areas. The complete solution is below. I am not happy about the solution to this outcome as mentioned below and welcome ideas. Basically I would have preferred a more agnostic binding of the resolve method to my states in the app.run file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working, although I am not quite happy with the code and I will explain at the end. First off, I found a path to my solution from this [Stackoverflow Prior Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630586/angularjs-dynamic-stateprovider-with-ui-router-views-and-oclazyload-resolves)

**1. app.js**

The only change I made from above was to add the ShellCtrl location:

> ```
> define(
> [
>     'angular', 'angular-ui-router', 'ocLazyLoad', 'config/common',
>     'layout/services/menuService', 'layout/controllers/ShellCtrl'],
>   
>     .....
> ```

**2. app.config:**

Nothing changed from above.

**3. app.run**

> ```
> define(['app'],function(app) {
> app.run(function ($q, $rootScope, $state, $window, menuSvc) {
>     menuSvc.all().success(function(states) {
>         angular.forEach(states, function (state) {>                
>             try{
>                /// for the Header
>                 state.views.header.resolve[state.views.header.data.controllerAlias] =
>                  function($ocLazyLoad){
>                     return $ocLazyLoad.load({
>                         "name": state.views.header.data.controllerAlias,
>                         "files": state.views.header.data.controllerFiles})};
>
>                /// for the Footer
>                 state.views.footer.resolve[state.views.footer.data.controllerAlias] =
>
>                  function($ocLazyLoad){
>                     return $ocLazyLoad.load({
>                         "name": state.views.footer.data.controllerAlias,
>                         "files": state.views.footer.data.controllerFiles})};
>             }catch(e){
>
>             }
>             console.log(state);
>             $stateProviderRef.state(state.name, state);
>         })
>       $state.go('app.dashboard');
>     })
> }); });
> ```

**4. With this as my JSON:**

> ```
> [   { "name": "app", "abstract": true, "url": "", "templateUrl": "app/layout/views/tpl.shell.html", "controller": "ShellCtrl" },   {
> "name": "app.dashboard",
> "views": {
>   "header": {
>     "templateUrl": "app/layout/views/tpl.header.html",
>     "controller": "HeaderCtrl as header",
>     "resolve": {},
>     "data": {
>       "controllerAlias": "app.layout",
>       "controllerFiles": [
>         "app/layout/layout.module.js",
>         "app/layout/controllers/HeaderCtrl.js"
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   "footer": {
>     "templateUrl": "app/layout/views/tpl.footer.html",
>     "controller": "FooterCtrl as footer",
>     "resolve": {},
>     "data": {
>       "controllerAlias": "app.layout",
>       "controllerFiles": [
>         "app/layout/layout.module.js",
>         "app/layout/controllers/FooterCtrl.js"
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> }   }]
> ```

**5. Shell.html**

> ```
>    <div data-ng-controller="ShellCtrl">{{shell.pageTitle}}
>    <div data-ui-view="header"></div> 
>    <div data-ui-view="footer"></div>
>    </div>
> ```

**6 Sample Controller:**

> ```
>    angular.module('app.layout').controller('HeaderCtrl', HeaderCtrl);
>
> /* @ngInject */
> function HeaderCtrl($scope) {
>     var header = this;
>     header.pageTitle = 'Response coming from HeaderCtrl';
> }
> ```

**7. With this as the output:**

[image]

**What I do not like:**

All components of my dashboard are interchangeable. Nothing is static. Depending on the "overall" view, the Header, Footer, SideMenu and Content all change. The link I mentioned above had only 1 interchangeable part, "the Feature" which I assume was main content.

I do not like the fact that I had to hard code each view in the my app.run relative to binding the resolve to each.

If someone knows how I can make this more agnostic, I would greatly appreciate input.

Answer (score 0):

> All components of my dashboard are interchangeable. Nothing is static. Depending on the "overall" view, the Header, Footer, SideMenu and Content all change. The link I mentioned above had only 1 interchangeable part, "the Feature" which I assume was main content.
>
> I do not like the fact that I had to hard code each view in the my app.run relative to binding the resolve to each.
>
> If someone knows how I can make this more agnostic, I would greatly appreciate input.

To make this more agnostic, you could implement something more along the lines of this.
Use object properties to iterate each and attempt to load into the respective resolve. Adding more error handling and checks would also help with stability.

**3. app.run**

```
 define(['app'],function(app) {
 app.run(function ($q, $rootScope, $state, $window, menuSvc) {
     menuSvc.all().success(function(states) {
         angular.forEach(states, function (state) {>                
             try{
                /// try to load for each each view
                for (var view in state.views)
                {
                   if (state.views[view]['data']){
                     state.views[view].resolve[state.views[view].data.controllerAlias] =
                          function($ocLazyLoad){
                              return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                    "name": state.views[view].data.controllerAlias,
                                    "files": state.views[view].data.controllerFiles
                              }
                           )};
                   }
                }
             }catch(e){

             }
             console.log(state);
             $stateProviderRef.state(state.name, state);
         })
       $state.go('app.dashboard');
     })
 }); });
```